# Propeller Display Code using 89c51 - Help Needed

Tags: c, microcontroller, 8051

Below is the code I have written for a propeller display that displays "HELLO" when run on a motor. The logic used for LEDs is active low which are connected to Port 1 which is declared as an output port. Port 3.2 is declared as an input port which is triggered by an IR Sensor. 
I have used Keil to compile this program and produce its hex file however when I burn it on my micro controller and run it, the pin 3.2 won't trigger any change in the output on Port 1. Ask any questions you're doubtful about in the comments and help me out. Thank you.

```
#include <reg52.h>

void delay_us(long num){ //function to delay 1 microsecond using tic
    long i;
    for(i=0;i<=num;i++){    
        TMOD = 0x01;
        TH0 = 0xFF;
        TL0 = 0xFE;
        TR0 =  1;
        while(TF0 == 0);
        TF0 = 0;
        TR0 = 0;
    }
}

void print_char(char input, long time) //function to print HELLO!
{
    if (input == 'H')
    {
        P1 = 0x3E;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x00;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x36;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x00;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x3E;
        delay_us(time);
    }
    else if (input == 'E')
    {
        P1 = 0x3E;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x00;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x14;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x1C;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x3E;
        delay_us(time);
    }
        if (input == 'L')
    {
        P1 = 0x3E;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x3E;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x00;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x3E;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x3E;
        delay_us(time);
    }
        if (input == 'O')
    {
        P1 = 0x3E;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x22;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x1C;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x22;
        delay_us(time);
                P1 = 0x3E;
        delay_us(time);
    }
}

//Declare Prototypes
int get_rpu();
sbit LED1 = P1^0;
sbit LED2 = P1^1;
sbit LED3 = P1^2;
sbit LED4 = P1^3;
sbit LED5 = P1^4;
sbit LED6 = P1^5;
sbit LED7 = P1^6;
sbit IR = P3^2;

void main()
{
    long delay_time; //degrees per microsecond

    P1 = 0x10; 
    P3 = 0x00; 

    //Initialize all LED's to be zero
    LED1 = 1;
    LED2 = 1;
    LED3 = 1;
    LED4 = 1;
    LED5 = 1;
    LED6 = 1;
    LED7 = 1;

    //get the amount of delay
   delay_us(1000);

    delay_time = (get_rpu() * 100) / 360;

    while (1) {
        //Wait for the sensor to start at reference point
        while (!IR);

        print_char('H',delay_time);
        delay_us(delay_time);
        print_char('E',delay_time);
        delay_us(delay_time);
        print_char('L',delay_time);
        delay_us(delay_time);
        print_char('L',delay_time);
        delay_us(delay_time);
        print_char('O',delay_time);

        //recalculate the spin rate
    delay_time = (get_rpu() * 100) / 360;
    }
}

int get_rpu() //function to calculate time per revolution
{
    int count = 0;

    while (!IR); //wait for first pass of the rate snesor

    //begin counting how many microseconds are there before the next pass
    while(IR)
    {
        delay_us(1);
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with P1^6?  ^ is exclusive or.  Are you trying to check the 6th bit?

Comment: Yes. I was trying to access the individual pins however I realized keil doesn't support this therefore now I have edited my program as you can see above.

Comment: Use (P1 & (1 << 6)) to access the 6th bit. ^ exclusive ORs with the bit pattern: it will not give you what you want

Comment: The [sbit](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_sbit.htm) keyword has behavior that many not familiar with Keil might not understand.